Spliting the input csv based on number of users in jmeter
I have an API which implements a Hit and Miss Cache approach. It is fetching data from DB to store in the cache.
I want to perform a performance test on the API where I send a unique record in every request. I am using a CSV file in Jmeter from which the records are getting picked.
its a list of 50000 unique Ids. In order to perform a concurrency test, I want to increase the number of users which will access the Ids from the CSV.
The condition is None of the Ids should be repeated by the users.
I know I can have multiple scripts(same as the number of users desired) run in parallel and perform the same test. But it is not feasible for 100 users.
I was looking for a way to do the same using a single jmeter script.

With default Sharing Mode of All Threads of the CSV Data Set Config each virtual user will pick the next line on each iteration and if you additionally set it to not to recycle on the end of file - your test will stop when the last value will be used and there will be no duplicate requests.

